# Unable to Download Packages via Android SDK Manager

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, sdk, adt

I have recently installed Android SDK on my computer running Windows 7 x64.

I then installed the Eclipse ADT plugin.  I am running Eclipse Juno JEE.

When I attempt to run the SDK Manager through Eclipse, I receive the following errors:

[image]

Nothing I have tried has allowed me to download/install/update Android SDK and its packages.

I have tried https and forcing http
I have tried running calling program as administrator.
I have added Eclipse, SDK Manager to Firewall exceptions.
I have turned off my antivirus.
I have turned off my firewall.
I have tried various combinations of the above.

I can navigate my browser to both URLs (using Firefox).  That should negate "Failed to read..." options 1 and 2.  Option 3 seems to be the likely candidate as the XML files do not, in fact, include the `<'xsd:schema'>` tag.  However, I don't know how, if, or where I might be able to point SDK Manager to a local, modified copy of these XML files, or if that would even solve anything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note:  I have installed Android SDK/ Eclipse ADT Plugin on the same machine in the past.  This is a fresh install after a recent reimage.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this answer's your question exactly to the point but yet I hope this helps you.

As u wrote it looks like you have downloaded eclipse from its website and android sdk separately from Android website. Why don't you download the Android SDK ADT package with pre-eclipse setup.

That will make your job way lot easier.
The file name would be something like this:

```
                  adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130729.zip
```

Comment: @ Lunar Inc. - I tried that as well and that didn't work.  Exact same error occurred.

Comment: @ Thomas Preston have you added jdk to windows path?
maybe ADT is not able to get access to java.
Just a blind shot here.